# Groovy, Jenkins, Submodule array

Tags: arrays, git, jenkins, groovy

I would like to create a groovy array for git submodule but unfortunately I always got back this error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

my code:

```
def submodule(){
        def submodulesList = sh(script:"git submodule init", returnStdout:true).split("\n")
   
          for( String[] submodule : submodulesList ) {

                  def submoduleName = submodule.split("'")[1]
                  def submoduleGitRepoUrl = submodule.split("\\(")[1].split("\\)")[0]

                  dir(submoduleName){
                      sh(script:"git submodule update", returnStdout:true)
                      git url: submoduleGitRepoUrl, branch: "master", credentialsId: 'cred'
                  }
         }
  }
```

Someone can help for me please?
Thank you,

Comment: Please edit your question and provide input and expected output. What's the value of `submodulesList` and expected list result

Comment: @daggett 

input:
Submodule 'submodule_name' (git@github.com:project/repo_name.git) registered for path 'foldername'

output (but it has to be check when only one line provided):
submoduleName == submodule_name
submoduleGitRepoUrl  == git@github.com:project/repo_name.git

Comment: please edit the question. don't use comments